# Filter nested json data using jsonpath as in example

Tags: java, jsonpath

I am using [jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to filter.

Json(Dummy json just to explain) source String, which is basically a list of Operating systems and details of its programs etc. In this example, the OS whose id = 1403 is a windows 10 OS and has 2 features acchritecture and browser. There are more details to the browser feature as shown in json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1403,
        "os": "window 10",
        "features": [
            {
                "id": 1356,
                "name": "architecture",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "id": 1308,
                        "feature": [
                            {
                                "id": 1262,
                                "key": "name",
                                "value": "amd64"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "category": "cat1"
            },
            {
                "id": 1357,
                "name": "browser",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "id": 1309,
                        "feature": [
                            {
                                "id": 1263,
                                "key": "name",
                                "value": "Firefox"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 1265,
                                "key": "version",
                                "value": "187"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "category": "cat2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2804,
        "os": "window 7",
        "features": [
            {
                "id": 2764,
                "name": "architecture",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "id": 2719,
                        "feature": [
                            {
                                "id": 2679,
                                "key": "name",
                                "value": "amd64"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "category": "cat1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2765,
                "name": "browser",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "id": 2722,
                        "feature": [
                            {
                                "id": 2685,
                                "key": "name",
                                "value": "Chrome"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2684,
                                "key": "version",
                                "value": "87.0.4280.88"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "category": "cat2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to be able to filter the json such that

```
features[*].name == 'browser' and features[*].value[*].feature[*].value == 'chrome'
```

What will be the JsonPath string that can help me achieve above query? The above query uses similar syntax used by JsonPath string but doesn't do the job. Its just to explain.

There is another example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath#2-getting-the-movie-title-given-starring) gets Movie Title Given 'Starring' field

And would like to get the full OS json that fulfils this condition. In this case a array of OS which contains only one OS i.e. with id= 2804

```
[
  {
    "id": "2804",
    ...
  }
]
```

I am stuck much before what aim to achieve. Here is my code to get all the OS that have "name=browser". I get the array but it only contains value[] items. I want it get the full json. It returns object with IDs- 1357, 2765.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> expensive = JsonPath.parse(jsonDataSourceString)
      .read("$[*].features[*].[?(@.name == 'browser')]");
```

Comment: Ok.  So what is your question?  This is a Question/Answer site.

Comment: I want to Filter out the content as explained. I am looking for a "jsonpath" string that can help me get that. The above jsonpath string doesn't do the job. I just listed that using the similar syntax used by jsonpath

Comment: State what you're looking for in the form of a question, like... "what is the jsonpath string that will give me the full OS record for just the OS that matches it", or something like that.  I think you should also show us your Python code.  If I understand correctly, a jsonstring all by itself doesn't "give you" anything?  You have to pass that string into a Java function to use it, right?  You should show us what behavior you're currently getting from your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the outer array you need to use the filter like `$[?(...)]`

For your current use case, we need to use nested array filters. There is an open issue in JsonPath for filter on children level. (Refer [here](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287)).

Luckily, there is a workaround suggested to use `contains` over [here](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287#issuecomment-731724846).

we can use the below expression to filter:

```
List<Object> expensive = JsonPath.parse(jsonDataSourceString)
                                 .read("$[?(@.features[?(@.name == 'browser')].value[*].feature[*].value contains 'Chrome')]");
```

Prints the below output

```
{id=2804, os=window 7, features=[{"id":2764,"name":"architecture","value":[{"id":2719,"feature":[{"id":2679,"key":"name","value":"amd64"}]}],"category":"cat1"},{"id":2765,"name":"browser","value":[{"id":2722,"feature":[{"id":2685,"key":"name","value":"Chrome"},{"id":2684,"key":"version","value":"87.0.4280.88"}]}],"category":"cat2"}]}
```

Comment: works like a charm. I had figured out the filter needs to be like $[?(...)] but the string I had need much more work to be able to reach that you suggested. Thanks for all the info links.